# How to open the binary log files generated by the tensor-board after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to open an output log file produced from training of a deep network model. I activated the tensor-board option during training to view the accuracy and learning during training. It created a directory call “tb” and placed the log files there. The files look like this:

```
events.out.tfevents.1519598682.sp
events.out.tfevents.1519600223.sp
events.out.tfevents.1519645064.sp
events.out.tfevents.1519651659.sp
```

I tried viewing the content of a file, but it’s a binary file.

Can anyone help me on how to view the files generated when you activate the tensor-board option?

I am using PyCharm with Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 1.14 in Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by typing the following in the linux terminal:

```
tensorboard --logdir=<path-to-log-directory>
```

Then I got the following:

```
TensorBoard 1.13.1 at http://computername:6006
```

and I just opened the above link in my firefox browser.